# Close button doesn't work when two modals are open

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two Bootstrap 4 modals open on a page. The first one is placed on the top and the second one on the bottom. Hovewer, the close button only works for the second modal because it most likely covers the first one when it's opened. How can I fix this? And could it be done without using z-index? Maybe there's something wrong in the way I wrote the html.

Here's my code:

```js
$('.modal').modal('show');
```

```css
.top {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.close {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-full modal" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="top">
      <button type="button" class="close mr-1" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      TEXT GOES HERE
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-full modal" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="bottom">
      <button type="button" class="close mr-1" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      TEXT GOES HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't use two modals, instead I'd use one a simply change the content dynamically

Comment: and also the closing tags `</top>` should be instead `</div>`

Comment: One small thing that I notice off the bat that is incorrect; you can't use the same `id` twice. Unlike classes, ids can only be applied to a single element.

Comment: @DelightedD0D But how can I close them separately then? If I use one modal, when you click on a close button, it would close them all. And thanks guys, I've edited the code. Sorry about that.

Comment: The real question is why are you displaying overlapping modals the first place? Seems like bad UI. I'm assuming something in the first modal triggers the second? Were it me, I'd clean up that presentation so that overlapping modals were not needed

Comment: Yeah, not my idea. Then maybe displaying them via modal is not the answer.

Comment: @Retros it seems (at least on my end) to be solved now with the fixes we made above?

Comment: @Jalen Davenport Still not working for me. But thank you, Jalen.

Comment: @Retros oh I get what you're saying now. Hmmm... My first thought would be maybe a modal isn't the best option?

Comment: @Jalen Davenport Yup, that's what I'm thinking, too. :/ Too bad, it was the easiest one. Well, until that happened. Haha